# %A_ThisHotkey% and foreign keyboard layout

Tags: autohotkey

```
h::
    send %A_ThisHotkey%
return
```

This code returns english "h" letter, even with foreign keyboard layout. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [A_ThisHotkey:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#ThisHotkey)
>
> The most recently executed hotkey or non-auto-replace hotstring (blank
> if none), in this case h.
>
> ```
> h:: MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey%
> ```

> [A_ThisLabel:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#ThisLabel)
>
> The name of the label (subroutine) that is currently executing (blank
> if none). Each double-colon hotkey also creates a label, unless it is
> a [function hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#Function).
>
> ```
> h:: MsgBox, %A_ThisLabel%
> ```

You can use

```
h:: send %A_ThisLabel%
```

in this case.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Because it's not defined in your script. The point of it is to avoid sending h in another keyboard layout.

Comment: I'll clarify my question a little: I want to add Ctrl-x-h combination:

h::
if(A_PriorHotkey = "^x")
{
    copyAll()
}
else
{
    send %A_ThisHotkey%
}
return

Comment: You're supposed to use a context sensitive hotkey for that. See [`#if`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_If.htm).